# Adding A-Z pagination in a custom Wordpress query

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, advanced-custom-fields

I've managed to set up a page template to show my custom post type 'books' and sort it by a custom field (the second name of the author):

```
<?php 
            // Define custom query parameters
            $custom_query_args = array(  
                'post_type' => 'books',
                'showposts' => 10,
                'meta_key' => 'author_second_name',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value date',
                'order' => 'ASC'
            );

            // Get current page and append to custom query parameters array
            $custom_query_args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

            // Instantiate custom query
            $custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );

            // Pagination fix
            $temp_query = $wp_query;
            $wp_query   = NULL;
            $wp_query   = $custom_query;

            // Output custom query loop
            if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
```

On my archive pages, I've successfully implemented A-Z pagination and have tried to adapt it do work on my author page using the below:

```
<?php echo "<a href=http://mywebsite.com/authors/?$query_string&number=true' ># </a> - ";

        foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $i)
        {
         $letter = strtolower($i);
            echo "<a href='mywebsite.com/authors/?$query_string&letter=$letter' >$i </a> - ";
        }
        echo "<a href=http://mywebsite.com/authors/?$query_string' >All </a>"; ?>
```

Somewhat unsurprisingly, this doesn't seem to work. I've Frankensteined various bits of code to get this far, and understand most of it in principle, but slightly stuck trying to get this to work.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I later found a much better way to query everything here:

http://wordpress.mcdspot.com/2012/04/12/select-posts-on-the-first-letter-of-a-custom-field/